# Cyclic polyynes

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Cyclic polyynes have been proposed as [theoretical compounds](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed200439u) to illustrate the “particle on a ring” model discussed in many quantum chemistry courses. I've looked it up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclocarbon) but there it's not clear whether one has ever been synthesised, or not.

So: have cyclic polyynes been synthesised? If not, what is the difficulty in achieving this?

Comment: This book [Polyynes: Synthesis, Properties and Applications, F. Cataldo ed.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=0OLLBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=synthesis%20of%20cyclic%20polyyne&ots=1SFuLuw64M&sig=_W_kXd9QeXkOwAk6gLx7inta9Vk#v=onepage&q=synthesis%20of%20cyclic%20polyyne&f=false) has a chapter on cyclic polyynes (chapter 6 by Y. Tobe and T. Wakabayashi). This suggests that they have been prepared.